# How do i get a "Login with Paypal" button to show up in a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal

Preface: I have 1 day of experience playing around with React.

Using this source code from a tutorial, which is set up to login with google. https://github.com/The-Tech-Tutor/spring-react-login

I want to add the "Login with Paypal" button to the Login.js page.

This is what PayPal generates for me.

```
<span id='lippButton'></span>


<script src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/api.js'></script>


<script>
paypal.use( ['login'], function (login) {
 login.render ({
   "appid":"sdfgaesdfgrfed",
   "scopes":"openid",
   "containerid":"lippButton",
   "responseType":"code",
   "locale":"en-us",
   "buttonType":"LWP",
   "buttonShape":"pill",
   "buttonSize":"lg",
   "fullPage":"false",
   "returnurl":"http://localhost:3000/profile"
 });
});
</script>
```

How do I get this third party js to work with React?

Thank you.

Comment: This is html code here, are you trying to do this in react? Is your question how you can link the PayPal code to a button in react? Please expatiate

Comment: Yes, From paypal I am given the above code, The span, which is the button container, and the js for the button. I am trying to figure out how to make that work in React

Comment: @TM did you get it working? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to take a look at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/log-in-with-paypal/ to get at least a deeper understanding what paypal is doing. I mean second day of react is may be a bit hard to integrate yourself, but as I can't assume your level of knowledge in general about web-dev (front + back) I think this is the way to go. From your code there is nothing suspicious only that you hopefully obfuscated your appId. Otherwise you need to create an appId in your Paypal-Account configure everything correctly (I guess especially the returnurl) and then use the provided appId.

If you only want to migrate the JS files to react look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-include-an-external-javascript-library-to-reactjs/
I would take the last approach (document.createElement) as is it fully under your control to a certain extent, especially for debugging.
You could also write the whole loader and use implement the paypal.use call inside the react component by using the callback when the script is loaded an then access the paypal.use method.

Comment: could you elaborate maybe with an example how to use that with document.createElement in React?

Comment: I know a bit late but...
In the link I provided, there is a explanation and code example. But in general you create a script tag that you append to the body but the trick is to do it completely in js and then react won't do react stuff it will just happen on the fly.